# Django South migration AttributeError

Tags: django, migration, django-south, attributeerror

I'm suffering from this error when migrating South (0.7.5) in Django (1.4). I recently changed the Timezone setting to false, i.e. USE_TZ = False to fix another problem. Any ideas? Thanks

```
~/code/django/ssc/dev/ssc/ssc: python manage.py migrate crewcal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 105, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 158, in migrate_app
    Migrations.calculate_dependencies()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 227, in calculate_dependencies
    migration.calculate_dependencies()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 355, in calculate_dependencies
    for migration in self._get_dependency_objects("depends_on"):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 335, in _get_dependency_objects
    for app, name in getattr(self.migration_class(), attrname, []):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 307, in migration_class
    return self.migration().Migration
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Migration'
~/code/django/ssc/dev/ssc/ssc:
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be too late, but I don't think it has anything to do with TZ.

Every migration file has a declaration like:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    ...
```

The `AttributeError` comes from not finding this Migration class declared.

Check whether all of your migrations have one like that. Otherwise please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

To second [Augusto Men](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317971/augusto-men)'s answer, the error is really about South being unable to find an implementation of `Migration` in a migration module. It's a general Python error message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Migration'
```

The error is thrown in [south.migration.base](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/0.8.4/south/migration/base.py#cl-315), now on line 315 (version 0.8.4)

### Debug Printout

Unfortunately, `python manage.py migrate` doesn't tell you which file is affected. You can help yourself by adding the following code above line 315 in `<your-virtualenv>/local/lib/python*/site-packages/south/migration/base.py`. This will tell you which file you have to work on.

```
print('## MODULE: %s' % str(self.migration()))
```

### Special Case

I had a special case with the `AttributeError` showing up for `migrations/<some_app>/__init__.py`, which is usually supposed to be just an empty file. The empty file stopped working after I added an **empty model** file `model.py` to my app to trick Django into looking at my app's `fixtures` folder (see [How to load Django fixtures from all apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167276/how-to-load-django-fixtures-from-all-apps/24460255#24460255)). I believe this is actually a South bug.

### Solution

As suggested above, find out which migration module is affected and simply add an empty implementation of a `Migration` class to that file, e.g.:

```
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration


class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        pass

    def backwards(self, orm):
        pass
```